# Could not find table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord

I don`t understand why I am getting the error:

```
could not find table libraryusers10s
```

In my code below, I define two tables `library_users10` and `library_books10` , and associate them with classes.

The following code works fine:

```
require 'active_record'
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter => "sqlite3",
    :database => "library8")

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :library_users10 do |table|
    table.column :user_id, :integer
    table.column :name, :string
    table.column :age, :string
    table.column :books_borrowed, :integer
  end

  create_table :library_books10 do |table|
    table.column :books_id, :integer
    table.column :borrower_id, :integer
    table.column :title, :string
    table.column :borrowed, :string
    table.column :due_back, :string
  end
end

class LibraryUsers10 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :library_books9s
end

class LibraryBooks10 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :library_users10s
end
```

But when I try to populate the table, by adding the following code to the script, I get the error `could not find table libraryusers10s`

```
libraryusers10 = LibraryUsers10.create(:user_id => 1, :name => 'Tom', :age => 10, :books_borrowed => 3 )
libraryusers10.library_books10.create(:borrower_id => 1, :title => 'Who let the dogs out?', :borrowed => '13_November_2013', :due_back => '21_November_2013' )
```

Does anybody have any suggestions as to what is going wrong here?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

The Rails convention is for table names to be pluralized

```
create_table :library_users10s do |table|
  ...

create_table :library_books10s do |table|
  ...
```

would fix things up for you.

If you cannot do that, then you can add a modifier to your models to skip the inflector like this:

```
class LibraryUsers10 < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'library_users10'
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

What i can guess is because of the 'S' at the end of the Class..For example:

Person.all queries the persons table.

I guess if you add a 's' when you create your tables it should work.

```
create_table :library_users10s
```

and

```
create_table :library_books10s
```

It should work.